# How can I check the value in a key-value nested list?

Tags: web-services, groovy, jsonslurper

I have created a REST web service.

I have in the response, a nested list with 5 key-value associations in each list.
I only want to check if each value has the right format (boolean, string or integer).

So this is the nested list.

```
{"marches": [
      {
      "id": 13,
      "libelle": "CAS",
      "libelleSite": "USA",
      "siteId": 1,
      "right": false,
      "active": true
   },
      {
      "id": 21,
      "libelle": "MQS",
      "libelleSite": "Spain",
      "siteId": 1,
      "right": false,
      "active": true
   },
      {
      "id": 1,
      "libelle": "ASCV",
      "libelleSite": "Italy",
      "siteId": 1,
      "right": false,
      "active": true
   }]
}
```

I use the JsonSlurper class to read the groovy response.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def responseMessage = messageExchange.response.responseContent
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(responseMessage)
```

With this following loop, I achieve in getting each block of list.

```
marches.each { n ->
    log.info "Nested $n \n"
}
```

I want for instance check if the value associated to the key "id", "13" is well an integer and so on.

Comment: just use nested each...

Comment: what exaclty do you want to do with the response? filter values or get a true/false answer?

Comment: I want to check if the response belongs to the good type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. Inside of the `.each`, `it` represents the nested object:

```
json.marches.each { 
  assert it.id instanceof Integer  // one way to do it

  //another way
  if( !(it.libelle instanceof String) ){
    log.info "${it.id} has bad libelle"
  } 

  //one more way
  return (it.libelleSite instanceof String) &&
     (it.siteId instanceof Integer) && (it.right instanceof Boolean)
}
```

If you don't care about the specifics and just want to make sure they're all good, you can also use `.every`:

```
assert json.marches.every {
    it.id instanceof Integer &&
    it.libelle instanceof String &&
    it.libelleSite instanceof String &&
    it.active instanceof Boolean  //...and so on
}
```